# d3 create border around legend under <g>

Tags: javascript, d3.js, legend

I want a box surrounding each individual legend whenever there is a `mouseover` event. My legend is formed in a way like this:

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(zColor.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    .style("zIndex", 1)
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 22 + ")";
    });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", xScale(d3.max(data, xValue)) * 1.05)
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .attr("fill", zColor)
/*
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
I want this effect to happen on the entire <g>, not just on the <rect>.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .on("mouseover", function () {
        d3.select(this).style("stroke-width", 2).style("stroke", "black");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        d3.select(this).style("stroke-width", 0);
    });
*/
legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", xScale(d3.max(data, xValue)) * 1.05 + 20)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d;
    });
```

How can I do it at `<g.legend>` level? I have tried to surround a `<div>` around each one, but the entire legend disappeared.

---

**[Update]**

This is what I did to append a `<div>` under `<g>` and group `<rect>` and `<text>` together. However, the legend is not plotted in this case.

```
var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(zColor.domain())
    .enter().append("g")
    .style("zIndex", 1)
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        return "translate(0," + i * 22 + ")";
    });
var legendDiv = legend.append("div").style("stroke-width", 2).style("stroke", "black");
legendDiv.append("rect")
    .attr("x", xScale(d3.max(data, xValue)) * 1.05)
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .attr("fill", zColor);
legendDiv.append("text")
    .attr("x", xScale(d3.max(data, xValue)) * 1.05 + 20)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .style("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When your code executes

```
legend.append("rect")
```

the result is the appended rectangle. (D3 is **not** like jQuery in this respect.)

Instead, you want

```
legend.on("mouseover", function() {/*...*/});     // ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. However, it still won't create a box outside the `<text>`, it just makes it bold. My question is really about making the `<g>` accept `<style stroke-width=2 stroke=black>`.

Comment: `<g>` elements are just groups, they don't have styles themselves. (although their styles can affect child elements)